# Javascript - Gather variables from dynamic created elements

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, dynamic, undefined

Basically this is the add function for my javascript

```
function Add(){
    var newDiv7 = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv7.setAttribute("class","StartDate");
    newDiv7.innerHTML = 'Description: <input type="text" name="Description[]">';
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newDiv7);
}
```

And this is my main form

```
<form name="MainDATA" method="POST" action="Executer.php" onSubmit="validate()">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="cmd">
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="Add()">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Validate javascript

```
function validate(){
    var y = document.forms["MainDATA"]["Description[]"];
    alert(y);
    //validation code
}
```

This code worked perfectly only if the user added a single `div` to my form. I was able to transfer my description onto `y` for validation, but when the user added 2 `div`s, then my `y` became `undefined`. What can I do in order to gather all the descriptions regardless of the amount of `div`s the user has added in?

Also, if I want to check to see if 'y' is atleast 10 characters in length, what can i do to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try `console.log(y);` ? Maybe you can do document.getElementsByClassName("StartDate") and get the children inside each div.

Comment: @Kaeros how does console.log(y) works? can you give me an example by testing variable 'y' with some methods like characters in length?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine.

Just counter variable was undefined.

```
var counter = 0;

function Add() {
    var newDiv7 = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv7.setAttribute("class", "StartDate");
    newDiv7.innerHTML = 'Description: <input type="text" name="Description[]">';
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newDiv7);
    document.getElementById("counter").value = counter;
}

function validate() {
    var y = document.forms["MainDATA"]["Description[]"];
    console.log(y);
    //validation code
}
```

Check out working example on [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UzQ9T/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem i'm having with this code is actually I have no idea on how to retrieve var y from javascript, for example, i want to see if user has entered more than 10 characters on description, how can i achieve that in my validate()?

Comment: @AnthonyCheng: y is list of your inputs so you have to loop through them to see what's in each input. I've updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UzQ9T/1/) so it displays char length in each input

Answer (score 0):

I ran this on Firefox 18 and worked it without any problem. Can you please try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vkxgd/)

```
f d()
```